# Add String to an ArrayList if only not empty

Tags: java, string, arraylist, stringbuilder

Supposing I have an `ArrayList < String >` named `arr` and a `StringBuilder` named `buf`, I use the following method to add the contents of `buf` to `arr`.

```
if ( !buf.toString( ).equals( "" ) ) {  //allow only non-empty Strings.
    arr.add( buf.toString( ) );
}
```

But it calls `buf.toString( )` twice. I don't want that in my code. Moreover, is there any other (short or easy or efficient or something else) way to achieve this?

EDIT: Also, I do this in a loop, so is this *efficient*?

Comment: `String s = buf.toString();` and use `s`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is API [`String#isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) method to check empty Strings in Java, use it. It will be more elegant.

```
String temp = buf.toString();

if (!temp.isEmpty()) {
    arr.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... didn't know that. Thanks. (Are there more such _elegant_ methods)?

Comment: @ambigram_maker, Yes, Check APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a `length()` method **instead of toString** because is a call for super class method and create new instance of String **so i recommend you a next :**

```
if(buf.length()>0)
{
  arr.add(buf.toString()); // one call!
}
```